# Catch outcome of jenkins job in shell command variable

Tags: shell, jenkins, cucumber

I have a job in Jenkins that uses two commands in a Execute Shell Command.
The first does a test job, the second creates a report out of this. It looks a littlebit like this:

```
node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js run-cucumber-tests
node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js create-cucumber-report
```

If there are test failures, the command will exit with code 1. This means the second command won't even be fired. But even though the first command failed, I want the report to be created!

What I've tried is to do this:

```
node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js run-cucumber-tests || true
node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js create-cucumber-report
```

Now the report does get created but the build is marked as succeeded. That's not what I want. I want the jenkins build job to eventually fail, but with the reports created.

I was wondering, maybe I can catch the outcome of the first command in a variable, continue with the second and *then* throw it after the second command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set +e` to let the script continue even if an error occurred and then use `$?` to capture the result of the last command. With `exit` you can force the result code of the script to the previously captured value.

```
set +e

node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js run-cucumber-tests
RESULT=$?

node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js create-cucumber-report

exit $RESULT
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, works like a dream! Thanks a bunch!